# What is the equivalent of "euphony" when applied to writing?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing-style, poetry, typography

In the details below, I use *something* to stand in for the word I am looking for. Speech may have *euphony*; writing may have *something*.

For example, when writing about the relative sizes of items, I might prefer to use "gigantic" and "tiny" as opposed to "big" and "minuscule," for consistency between word length and meaning. This has to do with the way the words appear on visually the page, not necessarily how they sound. In particular, the words chosen have *something* because of their *character (or letter) count*.

Clarification: I suppose "looks good" would be the meaning I am seeking (euphony is basically "sounds good" / "good sound"). *I am looking for a single word, though, that is specific to writing.* A lot of things that aren't writing "look good."

In response to @Zan700: he picks out that my above example is analogous to onomatopoeia. But here is another example: I might find words whose characters are all the same height to be pleasing to the eye, so for a user ID, I might pick "neo" instead of "Neo" (as Neo does in *The Matrix*). For simlar reasons, I might use the verb "peg" instead of "spike," because "spike" is *too* spiky in appearance (spikier than "peg"). In this example, the chosen  words have *something* because of the *shapes of the individual letters*.

Yet another example: in the following poem (yes, I checked the definition of poetry in the OED), the characters are arranged in a visually pleasing  manner: the antecedents line up vertically, as do the consequents, etc:

```
first <- function(x)
                                if
    (0  <  x %|% length) x[[1]] else if
    (x %|%    is.vector) x      else
                         NULL
```

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, so some would find the following, syntactically and semantically equivalent poem more pleasing:

```
first <- function(x) if (0 < x %|% length) x[[1]] else if (x %|% is.vector) x else NULL
```

The preceding poems have *something* because of their *layout*.

So the meaning I'm looking for is "looks good," *but not necessarily for any particular reason*, just as euphony does not, in and of itself, have a particular reason behind "sounding good" (it could sound good because it rhymes, because of alliteration, or because it sounds like one's own name).

If there is no such word, perhaps I could invent one (say, for use as a proper name in a fictional story, or in a poem). Someone with better Greek could make a suggestion. Perhaps *eumatia*?

Comment: Probably metrics: the art of metrical composition.

Comment: From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.  "

Comment: This is unclear. Are you referring to the lengths of words is written in letters?

Comment: "Eugraphy" would be my choice for a made up word - "good writing" or "written well". Because it's not appearance in general, it's the appearance of the written word specifically

Comment: @NoName , please make your Jun 4 comment into an answer.

Comment: The general word for literature engaging in some form of imitation is **mimesis**. But you are focusing on typographic imitation, which is not how the subject has been approached. Indeed, I would say it is a most peculiar approach, since literature is primarily a verbal art, a form of storytelling, not a form of graphic art.

Comment: Britannica says *The typographic page may be considered in terms of two aesthetic qualities. The first of these has been called “atmosphere,” “feel,” “impress,” “sense,” and other similar terms. It is easier felt than defined, and it depends in large measure on such things as the size of the block of type, its placement on the page, the kinds of display letters used for titles, running heads, and subheads, and the size of the margins—all elements that in the hands of a competent typographer create an expectation regarding the contents (possibly even the purpose) of the page*.

Comment: @StuartF  You could make the same claims about the book's price, or about which section of the bookstore it was shelved in.  Reading Shakespeare's sonnets in Comic Sans might be a different experience than reading them in Fraktur. But that's hardly the same thing as choosing **words** because of how they will look on the page, and what things might be evoked by the height of the letters, or by some other font-related feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inventing a word, it helps to make it fit in with the rest of the language. Because the word you are looking for is a specific parallel to "euphony" in the context of writing, a good choice is **eugraphy** - from the Greek for "good writing" or "written well". This could refer to the grammar, the letter forms, even the font, much like how euphony can refer to the (spoken) grammar, the phonetics, even the speaker's voice.

Comment: This is a from a comment promoted at the behest of OP

Comment: I am picking this as the answer.  The cursory Internet search I did suggests that "eugraphy" is not a euphemism for something sinister (what if the question had been about a word for "loves children?").

Answer (score 0):

**Typography** is the general concept. As defined at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography):

> Typography is the art and technique of arranging type to make written language legible, readable, and *appealing* when displayed.

If you're adjusting what length word you use in order to control the line length, margin, spacing, or other visual feature of a text, you are adjusting the typography. A more specific term is **[typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting)**, referring to the physical or digital arrangement of letters.

There's no one word like *euphony* for describing particularly aesthetic typography or typesetting. It would depend on what you were accomplishing.

Comment: What OP is describing has nothing to do with typography: 'I might prefer to use "gigantic" and "tiny" as opposed to "big" and "minuscule"'. This isn't the arrangement of text; it's word choice.

Comment: I used the typography tag _not_ because this question applied _exclusively_ to typography, but because it is _related_, and _could_ be applied to typography. I applied the poetry tag for the same reason.

Comment: @Laurel, it's word choice as adjusted by typographical criteria. They are selecting words based on typographical characteristics, just as one might select words based on euphonic characteristics

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to characterization through word choice. For example, "Bill Null" might be used to emphasize that a character is tall (all the tall l's). In your examples, it's visually matching the word to its meaning, and analogous to onomatopoeia.

Comment: I have edited my question in response to your post: "the meaning I'm looking for is 'looks good,' _but not necessarily for any particular reason_."

Comment: I've voted this down for the imprecision of your phrase "word choice".  You're not talking about the **words**, per se, but about the glyphs for the letters required to spell the word having ascenders, imitating tallness.  It's a glyph-driven choice, not a word-driven choice. Flaubert is rolling over in his grave.

Comment: @TimR But what you will set down on the page is a word. Your choice will be among words that contain glyphs. Ah, I'll chose LLLLLLLLLLLL for my character because the glyphs have ascenders.

Comment: It's not a lexical choice, strictly speaking, but a typographical one.  It has nothing to do with what the word means in speech, or even with how it sounds, but with the glyphs and fonts used to represent it on the page. Lower-case -L- in a cursive font might not have the same visual effect as a one in a condensed font.

Comment: It is both a lexical and typographical choice. If the word doesn't meet the lexical needs, the typography is irrelevant. Different fonts look different? Really?